# Update or switch BottomSheetDialogFragment inflated view when recyclerView dataset is changed

Tags: android, fragment

I have a BottomSheetDialogFragment and inside onCreateView i am inflating 2 different views based on a condition. Now my 1st view contains a recyclerView and the condition on which i want to switch my views is that if the list is empty then inflate view 1 else inflate view 2. Now my problem is when my list data count becomes 0 i want to call the onCreateView again so that based on the condition my 2nd view would be inflated. But i don't know how am i supposed to do it or rather is this the right way to do it.

My Code -

````
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (this.documentCount > 0) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout_document_attachments_added, container, false);

            documentArrayList = dataToRender.get(fieldPosition).getAttachments();

            Button attachMore = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_attachMore);
            if(documentCount == 5){
                attachMore.getBackground().setAlpha(128);
            }else{
                attachMore.getBackground().setAlpha(255);
            }

            attachMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{
                        if(documentCount == 5){
                            PageLoader.showToast(getResources().getString(R.string.document_limit_message));
                        }else{
                            pickDocuments();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Sentry.captureException(e);
                    }
                }
            });

            Button btnCloseDrawer = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_closeDrawer);
            btnCloseDrawer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

            recyclerview_documents = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_documents);
            adapter_documents = new DocumentAdapter(this, documentArrayList, fieldPosition);
            recyclerview_documents.setAdapter(adapter_documents);
            recyclerview_documents.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));

            return v;
        } else {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout_document, container, false);
            TextView txtview_attach = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtview_attach);
            txtview_attach.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{
                        permissionManager.checkPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, new PermissionManager.PermissionAskListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onNeedPermission() {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
                                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                                }, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionPreviouslyDenied() {
                                showDocumentRational();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionPreviouslyDeniedWithNeverAskAgain() {
                                dialogForSettings(getResources().getString(R.string.permission_denied), getResources().getString(R.string.permission_denied_document_access_message));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                                pickDocuments();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        Sentry.captureException(e);
                    }
                }
            });
            return v;
        }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Can't use more then one views for one fragment, but you can create a fragment wrapper that depends on the conditions, will show or create the fragment you need with the view you need.

for example WrapperFragment checking list size and creating Fragment1, when list size changed Wrapper fragment removung from fragment manager Fragment1 and add Fragment2